# How to passing data through multiple component in react?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have 3 components:
**Layout**
**App**
**Products**

My **Layout** has this form:

```
                  <form className='d-flex'>
                    <input
                      name='search'
                      className='form-control mr-2 shadow-none'
                      type='search'
                      placeholder='Search'
                      value={search}
                      onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <button className='btn btn-outline-secondary' type='submit'>
                      <SearchIcon />
                    </button>
                  </form>
```

I passed **search and setSearch** through props.

In my **App** has this logic:

```
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
    <Layout search={search} setSearch={setSearch}>  
        <Route exact path='/' search={search} component={Products} />
    </Layout>
```

I pulled the search result from the Layout and created a state in the App and then trying to pass to the Products component.

In the product when I try to console the search result I see only an undefined result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method doesn't work because you are passing the search value into the Route component instead of the component it render. You can use the render property of the Route to pass any props you want to the routing component https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-render-methods

```
 const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
 <Layout search={search} setSearch={setSearch}>  
    <Route exact path='/'
       render={props=> <Products {...props} search={search} setSearch={setSearch}/>} />
 </Layout>
```

However, I suggest using a state management tool like redux if the application is big or create a context provider https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context.